# XMLNS appearing on every node

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm creating a new XML Document using the following code:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
Dim docNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", Nothing, Nothing)
doc.AppendChild(docNode)

Dim rssNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("rss")
rssNode.Attributes.Append(doc.CreateAttribute("version")).Value = "2.0"
rssNode.Attributes.Append(doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:g")).Value = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
doc.AppendChild(rssNode)

Dim ChannelNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("channel")
rssNode.AppendChild(ChannelNode)
ChannelNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Title")).InnerText = "Product List"
ChannelNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("link")).InnerText = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
ChannelNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("description")).InnerText = "Web Site Product Links"
```

I'm then looping through my object list and adding items to the XML using this code:

```
    Dim itemNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("item")
    ChannelNode.AppendChild(itemNode)

    itemNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("g", "id", "g:id")).InnerText = item.id
```

While this does generate the XML document, it does it in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<channel>
    <Title>Product List</Title>
    <link>localhost</link>
    <description>Web Site Product Links</description>
    <item>
        <g:id xmlns:g="g:id">123456</g:id>
    </item>
</channel>
```

I'm after the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<channel>
    <Title>Product List</Title>
    <link>localhost</link>
    <description>Web Site Product Links</description>
    <item>
        <g:id>123456</g:id>
    </item>
</channel>
```

Everything I try seems to either remove the XMLNS attribute but also removes the "g:" from the element tag, I can't find the combination needed to remove just the XMLNS tag and leave it as in my example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your namespace in a variable:

```
Dim myNamespace as String = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
```

Then use that namespace in xmlns declaration:

```
rssNode.Attributes.Append(doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:g")).Value = myNamespace
```

And then when creating nodes:

```
itemNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("g", "id", myNamespace)).InnerText = item.id
```